# Is it possible to build a ground-based telescope that can directly image Earth-like planets orbiting in the habitable zone of sunlike stars?

Tags: telescope, exoplanet

In the following discussion I will refer to Earth-like exoplanets planets orbiting in the habitable zone of sunlike stars simply as “Earth-like exoplanets."

NASA is currently developing or considering three space telescopes that would be able to directly image Earth-like exoplanets:

- The WFIRST space telescope (if it’s equipped with a starshade).
- The HabEx space telescope, which would be equipped with both a starshade and
  a coronagraph.
- The LUVOIR space telescope, which would use a coronagraph to block the light 
  of an exoplanet’s star.

I can think of three possible reasons why it might not be feasible to build a ground-based telescope that can (like the three space-based telescopes) directly image Earth-like exoplanets:

- Reason 1: A starshade is one of the best technologies for blocking the light 
           of an exoplanet’s star, and it seems very difficult to use a 
           starshade with a ground-based telescope.

  Reason 1 seems valid, but it doesn’t seem that it can be the whole story 
  because (as discussed above) the LUVOIR telescope will only use a coronagraph 
  to block the light of an exoplanet’s star, and the HabEx telescope will use a 
  starshade for some observations and a coronagraph for other observations.
- Reason 2: Maybe the type of coronagraphs planned for the LUVOIR and HabEx 
           telescopes wouldn’t work for a ground-based telescope.
- Reason 3: One of the main reasons why scientists want to directly image 
           Earth-like exoplanets is to spectroscopically examine their 
           atmospheres to look for possible signs of life such as oxygen and 
           methane. Maybe spectroscopically examining the atmospheres of 
           Earth-like exoplanets requires imaging in the infrared spectrum, 
           which isn’t possible for ground-based telescopes.

Are these three reasons valid, and do they imply that it isn’t feasible to build a ground-based telescope that can directly image Earth-like exoplanets? Are there other factors that need to be considered? Or is it actually possible to build a ground-based telescope that can directly image Earth-like exoplanets?

Comment: Check https://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/eelt/science/ and you will see that the prospects from ground for the next generation of giant telescopes is not great for what you want. Direct Imaging so close in needs next-gen coronography and image stability that can only be provided in space. For your point 3.) taking a spectrum requires vastly different equipment and is in a way simpler, particularly now that high-resolution radial velocity spectrographic techniques are being developed. Those can give you an atmospheric spectrum from the ground that's RV-separated from the stars, if strong enough

Comment: How much money do you have?  In seriousness - large effective aperture scopes with high-density adaptive optic systems, plus all the blocking and filtering you refer to are technologically possible but at a cost (I believe) exceeding that of a space-based system including launch.